# C# selenium wont find webdriver from directory

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I cannot get selenium to find my webdrivers, wether it be firefox or chrome. I have tried downloading the dirvers manually and with the NuGet package manager, neither of them are working for me in C# but with python they work fine.

C# code that does not work. Gives out error:

```
Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException' in WebDriver.dll
An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
The file C:/webdrivers/geckodriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
```

Commeted code, found on some old stackoverflow question did not work either

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;    
class Scraper
    {
        /*
        private static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
        public static IWebDriver Init()
        {
            //System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.gecko.driver", @"C:\webdrivers\geckodriver.exe");
            FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\webdrivers");
            service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"; // May not be necessary
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            Driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options, time);
            return Driver;
        }
        */
        IWebDriver driver;
        public void StartScraping()
        {
            //driver = Init();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(@"C:/webdrivers/");
        }
    }
```

Calling the StartScraping() from UWP applications MainPage.xaml.cs constructor

Python code that works just fine

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, Chrome


def startf():
    driverf = Firefox("C:/webdrivers/")
    driverf.get("https://www.google.com")


startf()
```

Some have said that I should add the webdrivers directory to PATH, that I've done as well but nothing changed

EDIT:
After returning to this problem a couple of days later and testing selenium with just a console application and it working properly there.
This would seem to be a problem with me using a blank Universal Windows Platform application instead of a Console App. Is there a way to "attach" or open a console window inside a UWP application? Or could that even fix this issue? if not, can I somehow open similar XML form window from a console application?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get rid of this is to use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` in the path instead of using `/` or `\\`.
You can use it like:

```
separator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
path = $"C:{separator}webdrivers{separator}";
```

And now you can use this `path` while running firefox.

Comment: does not work with:

char separator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;


driver = new FirefoxDriver($"C:{separator}webdrivers{separator}");


driver.Url = "https://www.google.com";

still returning the same error

Comment: @Lauri try using `driver = new FirefoxDriver(@"C:\\webdrivers\\");` and let me know if this works. It's basically using two backward slashes instead of one forward slash

Comment: @Lauri which system are you using? Windows linux or mac?

Comment: i'm using windows.